How to identify which process hooks into a keybinding?
For some reason Alt+R does not work on my system as keybinding at all. I am sure it did use to work. I am wondering if there is an API on windows that can tell me which processes are hooking into keybindings, because in the past it was GeForce Experience, but now some other process seems to intercept the keybinding.
Perhaps there is not even an API for this, since i would need to observe an event that does not seem to be propagated properly by whichever process swallows the event.
Any suggestions are welcome

No api for that.  Use Task Manager and kill processes one by one to find the evildoer.

Guess that is one workaround to find the evildoer indeed. Thanks for the suggestion

SetWindowsHookEx(WH_DEBUG, ...) but WH_KEYBOARD_LL (the most common keyboard hook) is not on the documented list so you might not catch it (it will catch WH_KEYBOARD though).
The non-programmatic way of just killing non-Microsoft processes until the problem goes away is probably better and faster in your case...

Thanks, i will have a look at it and upvote accordingly. With another hook i did i did not even get the hook event for alt+r, while i did get it for other events, but yes, i also thought about killing processes which i do dislike. Perhaps i can find an API call to temporarily pause a process, but yeah. first i'll try your suggestion
